# Find text in Word, and select content from range

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I want to find some word, or sentence within a Word document. Then I want to select whole document below that row which contains word/sentence (including that row). After that, to copy content and to paste it into an excel sheet.

I am stuck with selection of ranges.

Edit: There is only one unique sentence.

Please review my code:

```
Sub importDocfile()
    Dim rng0 As Word.Range
    Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object
    Dim myRange As Word.Range
    Dim strTheText As String
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    'word ll be close to run
    WordApp.Visible = True
    'open the file .doc
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Personality    analysis and profile.docx")
    Set myRange = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="OPQ32" ' Here I dont know how to declare my start range
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range
myRange.Find.Execute "OPQ32"

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range( _
    Start:=myRange.Start, _
    End:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count).Range.End)
```

Comment: no, I'm affraid not. It is red code, and whem I try to run it, it gives me an error "Syntax error". I've tried to write the code in one line, removing Findtext:= and "_", as well as End:=, but still I cant m ake it to work.

Comment: try again. I misspelled paragraphs in the `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count` syntax. I fixed it.

Comment: Still the same, red code and "syntax error". Maybe we need parenthesis before FIndText ?

Comment: No problem.  Now, it's error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method. :)

Comment: Okay. I think I got it now. I misunderstood the `.Find` method, but just tested my edited code and it worked for me.